# Generating Personal Calendar for each user id

Tags: mysql

I need your help to make query to select date per user id.

i have employee table

```
+----------------------+
| id  user_id userfname|
+----------------------+
| 1   6001    Richard  |
| 2   6002    Jake     |
| 3   6003    Nelson   |
+----------------------+
```

i just generate calendar table like

```
+----------+------------+
|   id     |  db_date   |
+----------+------------+
| 20200601 | 2020-06-01 |
| 20200602 | 2020-06-02 |
| 20200603 | 2020-06-03 |
| 20200604 | 2020-06-04 |
| 20200605 | 2020-06-05 |
| 20200606 | 2020-06-06 |
+----------+------------+
```

I want result like

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
| db_date     | user_id | userfname|
+-------------+---------+----------+
| 2020-06-01  | 6001    | Richard  |
| 2020-06-01  | 6002    | Jake     |
| 2020-06-01  | 6003    | Nelson   |
| 2020-06-02  | 6001    | Richard  |
| 2020-06-02  | 6002    | Jake     |
| 2020-06-02  | 6003    | Nelson   |
| 2020-06-03  | 6001    | Richard  |
| 2020-06-03  | 6002    | Jake     |
| 2020-06-03  | 6003    | Richard  |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

I have been using this query with cross join

```
select db_date, user_id, userfname from user,generate_table
```

My question how i can make this more simple and effective without generate calendar?

Btw im using mysql

Comment: *My question how i can make this more simple* I do not see the way to make it MORE simple. *without generate calendar* No way - it is needed. You may do not generate static calendar table but generate it dynamically in the query.

Comment: @Akina maybe you have any recomendation query to execute some query into just one?

Comment: MySQL version is ... ?

Comment: Simpler would be to handle issues of data display in application code